# Eclipse plugin for auto import java classes

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is there a plugin in eclipse that when you type 'new JavaClass' it will auto import like 'import java.class.JavaClass' just like in FlashDevelop where-in when you type 'new MovieClip' it will put automatically 'import flash.display.MovieClip' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type a class name without the package, invoke the Content Assist feature by pressing Ctrl+Space (on Mac, use Command+Space) and Eclipse will auto-complete it by adding an import statement. You can also use the Organize Imports shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+o or Command+Shift+o) at any time to complete and organize the imports.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependent libraries locations are added to Eclipse, eclipse does that by default. There is no need for a separate plugin for it.